# How to set password for redis-server

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, sentinel, redis-sentinel, redis-server

I have a 3-instance high availability redis deployed. On each server I have redis and sentinel installed. I am trying to set a password
so that it requests it at the moment of entering with the command "redis-cli".

I am modifying the value of the "requirepass" parameter of the "redis.conf" file.

`requirepass password123`

Also inside the redis terminal, I am setting the password with the following commands

```
config set requirepass password123
auth password123
```

When I connect with the following command

```
redis-cli --tls --cert /<path>/redis.crt --key /<path>/redis.key --cacert /<path>/ca.crt -a password123
```

It works fine, my problem is when I restart the redis service, for some reason the password settings are not kept and I get the following message

```
Warning: AUTH failed
```

I do not know what configuration I need to do so that the change is maintained after restarting the redis service.

The version of redis that I have installed is "Redis server v=6.0.6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your ACL configuration,Your `requirepass` configuration will be ignored with ACL operation. I get follow infomation from redis.conf example file.

> IMPORTANT NOTE: starting with Redis 6 "requirepass" is just a compatibility
> layer on top of the new ACL system. The option effect will be just setting
> the password for the default user. Clients will still authenticate using
> AUTH  as usually, or more explicitly with AUTH default 
> if they follow the new protocol: both will work.
> The requirepass is not compatable with aclfile option and the ACL LOAD
> command, these will cause requirepass to be ignored.

Comment: You are right, I am checking the redis ACL and I see that the default user has configured not to use password

1) "user default on nopass ~* +@all"

Is it possible to assign a password to the default user?

Comment: yes, you can assign password to default user. try `ACL SETUSER default on >newpass ~* +@all`

Comment: Thanks, testing this command I see that the default user is assigned a password. My only problem is that with that command, the password is temporary. If I restart the redis service it goes back to "nopass". Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/acl  There are two ways in order to store users inside the Redis configuration.
1. Users can be specified directly inside the `redis.conf` file.
2. It is possible to specify an external ACL file.

Comment: I managed to set the password permanently for the default user. Adding these 2 parameters in the file "redis.conf"

`requirepass newpass123`
`masterauth newpass123`

And in the file "sentinel.conf"

`sentinel auth-pass mymaster newpass123`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
config rewrite
```

This command will solve your issue of nopass after restart.
After setting the requirepass from redis cli.